# cd into directory in while loop doesn't work

Tags: bash

I've the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash

ls -1 | while read d
do 
    [[ -f "$d" ]] && continue
    echo $d
    cd $d
done
```

Problem is that each cd says "[path]: No such file or directory", why?
Folder exists because I list it ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I see two problems in your code:

1. You do not test for directories.
2. Once you `cd` in the dir, you stay there.

Please try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

ls -1 | while read d
do 
    test -d "$d" || continue
    echo $d
    (cd $d ; echo "In ${PWD}")
done
```

Answer (score 6):

You shouldn't use `ls` like that.

```
#!/bin/bash

for d in */
do 
    [[ ! -d "$d" ]] && continue
    echo "$d"
    cd "$d"
    # do something
    cd "$OLDPWD"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you change the working directory in your script. This means that the second `cd` will be executed in the subdirectory you entered in the previous `cd`.

```
dir=`pwd`
ls -1 | while read d
do 
    [[ -f "$d" ]] && continue
    cd "$dir"
    echo $d
    cd $d
    #....
done
```

Comment: Does your directory name contain space(s)?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what you are trying to achive. 
Do you want to do some kind of recursive dic traversal ?

Here's ho I would do it:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
CWD="$(pwd)" #save starting directory
ls -1 | while read d
do
    [[ ! -d "$d" ]] && continue
    cd "$d"
    echo "Changed to directory" $d
    #Now you can do someting in the sub-directory
    cd "$CWD" #Change back to old directory
done
```